# How to reset numbering for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, numbering, moderncv

I am having problem of how to reset numbering for different types of references. I used biblatex in combination with modernCV. The reference list is divided into "journal papers" and "conference papers". However the numbering that appeared goes like this for journal papers : 1, 2, 4, 5 and for conference papers: 3. The desired numbering goes like this for journal papers : 1, 2, 3, 4 and for conference papers: 1. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true, backend=bibtex, maxbibnames=99,doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\defbibnote{pro}{}
\defbibnote{ar}{}
\bibliography{myPub} 

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{% label format from numeric.bbx
        \printfield{prefixnumber}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}% layout parameters from moderncvstyleclassic.sty
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{\hintscolumnwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \leftmargin\labelwidth%
      \advance\leftmargin\labelsep}%
      \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\moderncvstyle{oldstyle}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}       
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[prenote=ar, type=article, title={Articles},resetnumbers=true]
\printbibliography[prenote=pro, type=inproceedings, title={Conference proceedings},resetnumbers=true] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. As it stands, your issue cannot be reproduced by anybody without a copy of `myPub.bib`. You should add an example set of entries which can be used to reproduce the issue. However, if you do not redefine the `bibliography` environment, delete the generated files (`.aux`, `.bbl` etc.) and recompile, does it work better?

Comment: This works fine for me.  You need to compile it a couple of times *after* running `bibtex` to get the numbers right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting and renumbering takes (at least) two `latex` compilations *after* running `bibtex` to get the numbers sorted out properly.